# Modificar valores de inputs de otras páginas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, json

Estoy desarrollando una extensión para Google Chrome que me autocomplete formularios de diferentes páginas web, obviamente tengo conocimientos en html css y javascript, pero no se si hay alguna forma de manipular los valores de los input de otras web a través de un script alojado en la extensión.

Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

En el manifest.json de tu extensión puedes especificar los archivos js que se van a cargar en diferentes páginas.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que vas a modificar Twitter, Facebook, Myspace, Instagram y StackOverflow tienes que cargar los archivos, twitter.js, facebook.js, myspace.js, instagram.js y stackoverflow.js en cada uno.

Tu manifest.json quedaría algo similar a esto. Donde por cada página mandas a llamar a un archivo javascript diferente.

```
{

    "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
    "https://twitter.com/"
    ],
    "js": [
    "js/twitter.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ],
    "matches": [
    "https:facebook.com/"
    ],
    "js": [
    "js/facebook.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ],
}
```